# System.InvalidOperationException when modifiying value in an xml file in C#

Tags: c#, xml

So i... Have this snippet of code what writes to an existing xml file... the code to me is VERY simple...

```
            XElement element;
            XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(FileLoc);
            element = xdoc.Elements(XName.Get("gold", "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/DumaLegend")).Single();
            element.Value = Gold.Text;
```

Good Right? good! but why does it give out that error which means that it can't find the thing? it's a very valid thing....

here is the xml file:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Save xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/DumaLegend">
  <saveInfo>
    <energyPieces>0</energyPieces>
    <fullEnergyCells>4</fullEnergyCells>
    <fullHearts>4</fullHearts>
    <globalSwitches xmlns:d3p1="a">
      <d3p1:switchList xmlns:d4p1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays" />
    </globalSwitches>
    <gold>0</gold>
    <hasBigFireball>false</hasBigFireball>
    <hasCombo>false</hasCombo>
    <hasCrossbow>false</hasCrossbow>
    <hasDash>false</hasDash>
    <hasDashUpgrade>false</hasDashUpgrade>
    <hasDoubleJump>false</hasDoubleJump>
    <hasFireball>false</hasFireball>
    <hasHookshot>false</hasHookshot>
    <hasInvisPot>false</hasInvisPot>
    <hasSecondCombo>false</hasSecondCombo>
    <hasShieldUpgrade>false</hasShieldUpgrade>
    <hasSmallFireball>false</hasSmallFireball>
    <heartPieces>0</heartPieces>
    <heroPosOnMap>0</heroPosOnMap>
    <heroTokens>0</heroTokens>
    <itemSlot1 xmlns:d3p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/DumaLegend.Objects.Consumables" i:nil="true" />
    <itemSlot2 xmlns:d3p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/DumaLegend.Objects.Consumables" i:nil="true" />
    <lives>3</lives>
    <worldsUnlocked>0</worldsUnlocked>
    <worldsUnlockedOnMap>0</worldsUnlockedOnMap>
  </saveInfo>
  <saveSlot>0</saveSlot>
</Save>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `xdoc.Descendants(XName.Get("gold", "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/DumaLegend"))`.

Answer (score 0):

From [the docs for `Elements`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348975(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Returns a filtered collection of the **child elements of this element or document**, in document order. Only elements that have a matching `XName` are included in the collection.

There is only one child elements of your document, and that is the `Save` element.

What you are looking for is at the path `Save/saveInfo/gold`. So you can either use `Elements` like this:

```
XNamespace ns = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/DumaLegend";
var gold = doc.Elements(ns + "Save")
    .Elements(ns + "saveInfo")
    .Elements(ns + "gold")
    .Single();
```

Or you can use [`Descendants`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353813(v=vs.110).aspx), which will search all child elements recursively.

```
XNamespace ns = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/DumaLegend";
var gold = doc.Descendants(ns + "gold").Single();
```